# Exception mechanism not working

Tags: c++, exception, portable-executable, loadlibrary

I have a simple dll project, when dll is loaded it creates thread with code:

```
try
{
    throw std::exception("Not working");
}
catch (std::exception &err)
{
    printf("error %s\n", err.what());
}
catch (...)
{
    printf("unhandled\n");
}
```

But this code not working, it still telling me about unhandled exception
Also I should say that problem in my loader
I'm using own pe-mapper which loading dll without LoadLibrary
So same code working in seperate exe or even with simple injection
Obviously, for some reason the mechanism is broken, I solved the problems before, for example with fmath
Question is what should I do to make exception mechanism working?
What conditions does LoadLibrary for it?

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in C++ code?

Comment: `std::exception`'s constructor doesn't expect any argument. What happens if you add `const` to the first catch clause (`catch (const std::exception &err)`?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Mario. It's still telling about unhandled exception
I think problem in my loader...

Comment: This code should NOT compile as `std::exception` does not take a C-string parameter on it's constructor see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception  . Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also are you trying to create the thread in `DllMain` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten - absolute no any different where thread created. if it for example created in `DllMain` - so what ?! simply interesting

Comment: Nothing will happen. My loader copying loader into process and running remote thread, so don't matter if it started from dllmain.
Constructors:
_EXCEPTION_INLINE std::exception::exception()
_EXCEPTION_INLINE std::exception::exception(const char * const & _What)
_EXCEPTION_INLINE std::exception::exception(const char * const & _What, int)
_EXCEPTION_INLINE std::exception::exception(const exception & _That)
Idk what are you talking about

Comment: if you want exception handling - your loader **must** use `LdrLoadDll` or `LoadLibrary[Ex]` for load your code. no another way. and are thread started in DllMain or not - at all absolute unrelated here. at all - what different from what function in some dll it started ?

Comment: @RbMm When `DllMain` is called your process is inside a kernel loader lock - you should do nothing while at all whilst this lock is held.  There are are many post on this subject (including Microsoft official docs).

Comment: @RichardCritten - you absolute mistake. `DllMain` really called inside *user mode* loader lock - and so what ?!? we **can** create thread inside *DllMain* - this is absolute correct and legal. we can not **wait** on thread begin execute or exit - because it also will be try enter to this lock. but we wait inside this lock. but again - create thread we free can. and how this can affect exception handlers in this thread ?!?

Comment: @RbMm staing (and a lot more in the same link) with _"Warning  There are significant limits on what you can safely do in a DLL entry point. See General Best Practices for specific Windows APIs that are unsafe to call in DllMain. If you need anything but the simplest initialization then do that in an initialization function for the DLL. You can require applications to call the initialization function after DllMain has run and before they call any other functions in the DLL."_ source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten - i all know this very well. however not all what writed in this article true. call *CreateThread* in *DllMain* is **absolute correct and absolute safe** - not risky. no exception. are this not clear or understand ? nothing prevent from do this. we can not **wait** for thread - because thread at startup will try enter to dll loader lock. but we hold this lock. we will be wait for this thread and thread will be wait when we free lock. so **wait** and only **wait** for thread we can not. buy again and again create thread we **can**. i in details explain to you why this.

Comment: @RichardCritten - need deep understand windows internals. need understand what we do. not only read documentation. documentation some times changed. some times containing errors or just lie.  about *CreateThread* - i explain in details why we can call it in DllMain and why can not wait when this thread exit or say signal some event. can you argue your position, why we can not call *CreateThread* from *DllMain* - and not based on **bad** documentation but on yourself knowledge ?

Comment: @RichardCritten: Creating a thread inside `DllMain` is safe, synchronizing with that thread, on the other hand, causes a deadlock. Since you usually want to synchronize with a thread you are passing data to, it is commonly recommended to not create any threads inside `DllMain`. [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn’t it?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) has more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I should say that problem in my loader I'm using own pe-mapper
>   which loading dll without LoadLibrary

this is exactly cause why any exception handlers will be not work in your code. you need only use `LoadLibrary` or `LdrLoadDll` for exception work. however even with `LoadLibrary` exist way load file from memory only - not from disk, but this is another story

---

why ? you can ask. because *RtlDispatchException* - api which do exception dispatching - not unconditionally call exception handlers, but do many checks before this. it check are address of handler inside some *DLL*. if yes and this *DLL* have [safe SEH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429.aspx) - are handler address registered. if not in any *DLL* - are memory in where handler is in **section** (file mapping on win32 language) and are this section mapped **as image** (with `SEC_IMAGE` attribute) - otherwise this handler will be ignored. in case x64 - handlers at all not registred in *TEB* but in *DLL* section only (look `RUNTIME_FUNCTION` ). so system walk by list of *DLL* loaded for found handler address - look for [`RtlLookupFunctionEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680597(v=vs.85).aspx) - so if your code will be not in *DLL* list sytem at all not found your handler.

again exception handling not worked because and only because you not load your code with `LoadLibrary`

Comment: Thank you for answer, anyway I have no chance for LoadLibrary, so I will rewrite my code to result handling instead of exceptions

Comment: @Annett - you mistake. you **can** use load library. simply you don't know how. can only hint - exist elegant and 100% working way do this. of course not trivial, but this is possible - load your image **from memory** with this api

Comment: I also need to process obfuscation of my module, and do not save headers, and do not declare dll in process modules, so only custom loader

Comment: if your code will be not listed in process modules list - x64 at all not found your handler. in x86 - was checks, which become more verbose with every new version. yearly was checked - if handler not in any dll - it must be in image section only. may be now even this disabled - I not check. really only legal registered dll can have exception handlers.